# Nunit System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, nunit-console

I'm having some trouble running my tests from command line. I have a separate project for the tests and usually using Rider where the tests run flawlessly. However, I want to run them in a CI environment and therefore need to be able to run them form command line.

I'm trying to run
    Projectname>"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" Test\Test.csproj
    NUnit Console Runner 3.4.0
    Copyright (C) 2016 Charlie Poole

```
Runtime Environment
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000

Test Files
    Test\Test.csproj

Errors and Failures

1) Error : Test.MVCmodel.CoilClassTest.CoilCreateEmptyIdTest
System.BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly 'UserInterface, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
   at Test.MVCmodel.CoilClassTest.CoilCreateEmptyIdTest()
```

The same thing happens when running
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" Test\bin\Debug\Test.dll

The Test Project is located inside the MainProject: Projectname\Projectname.csproj and Projectname\Test\Test.csproj

And yes, I have found quite a few posts similar on Stackoverflow, but I found no applicable solution.

Comment: 32-bit process vs. 64-bit process almost certainly. Make sure your application and test project is compiled for the right type of target.

Comment: Agreed. This is normally auto-detected by nunit - you're using quite an old version of the nunit console - I'd recommend trying the latest version.

Comment: Ah - I missed you're passing the csproj in instead of the assembly. That may also affect what is automatically recognised. There's an `--x86` flag, if you need to force x86

Comment: Yes, thank you, the --86 flag did it. It seems I also had different versions of nunit for my main project and my Test project....

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me. Under build settings change the platform target to x86

[image]

This of course is assuming that UserInterface exists and runs well outside of the CLI environment (like in visual studio)